# OleObject Android

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, android

Приветствую, встала задача, реализовать нажатие на кнопку в WebBrowser, но ни в какую не хочет работать с OleObject, может кто подсказать?
Просьба не писать мне юзать эклипс и прочее, задача поставлена именно на XE6 Delphi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

на андроиде нет oleobject. Да, там есть webview, но это не ole объект. Поэтому, не будет работать код, если Вы его собрались писать таким способом.

Если хотите писать под андроид, почитайте о платформе. Нельзя писать под одну платформу, используя идеологию другой.

Comment: Спасибо, а Вы могли бы мне подсказать примерно, как совершить клик по кнопке зная только её название?

Comment: у WebView есть метод evaluateJavascript. Он должен помочь.

Comment: webView я так полагаю это сторонний компонент?

Comment: в андроиде этот "компонент" - [стандартная поставка](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) и практически часть системы. Как оно в делфи будет - даже не представляю.